# "You did not sign in correctly or your account is temporarily disabled."

Tags: login

I have just been invited to a Magento site. Never recieved an email that I was added as user.
Was able to go to the site and "reset password", but now I get the "You did not sign in correctly or your account is temporarily disabled." error every time.

Even had the person try to add a user with another email. Same story.

What gives? Any suggestions?

Best regards!

Comment: you are asking to magento 2??? And this error showing in admin panel login???

Comment: maybe you account is not confirmed yet. but you should ask the devs/admins of the site

Comment: If it's admin user then ask the Administrator to try running below command in case the account is locked:
`php bin/magento admin:user:unlock <username>`